# How to import GstPbutils?

Tags: python-3.x, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to use the GstPbutils python3 module, but just importing it breaks everything, here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi
gi.require_version('GstPbutils', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GstPbutils

print('Hello World!')
```

And the output:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py:178: Warning: g_array_append_vals: assertion 'array' failed
  g_type = info.get_g_type()
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py:178: Warning: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
  g_type = info.get_g_type()
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py:178: Warning: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
  g_type = info.get_g_type()
Hello World!
```

Is my distribution broken? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Those are just warnings, everything should works fine, anyway you can remove them using the following code:

```
import sys
sys.modules["gi.overrides.Gst"] = None
sys.modules["gi.overrides.GstPbutils"] = None
```

Source: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736260